# role annotation in google chart

Tags: c#, sql, charts, google-visualization

i wanna add 
role:'annotation'
to show up the value 
but i don't know how .. 
and
if there any other way to make tooltip always showing please tell me how
thanks
editing :
if there any other way to make tooltip always showing please tell me how
thanks
editing :

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            title: 'Ticket Encours',
            width: 1700,
            height: 400,
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
            legend: 'none',
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9  },
            curveType: 'function',
            pointSize: 10,
               tooltip: {trigger: 'both'},
        selectionMode: 'multiple',
        aggregationTarget: 'none'

        };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home.aspx/GetLineChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                 var view = google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, {
              calc: 'stringify',
              sourceColumn: 1,
              type: 'string',
              role: 'annotation'
            }]);

                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart_Line")[0]);
                 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
              var rows = [];
              data.getSortedRows({column: 0}).forEach(function (row) {
                rows.push({row: row, column: 1});
              });
              chart.setSelection(rows);
            });

            chart.draw(view, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**annotations**

we can use a data view to add the annotation role.
we need to add the role after each series in the data table.

first, create the data view from the data table.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
```

then use the `setColumns` method on the data view,
we include the column indexes of the original data table columns,
then add the role.

```
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: 'stringify',
  sourceColumn: 1,
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'              
}]);
```

if you have more than one series, for instance 2, then it would be...

```
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: 'stringify',
  sourceColumn: 1,
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'              
}, 2, {
  calc: 'stringify',
  sourceColumn: 2,
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'              
}]);
```

following is the full snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        title: 'Ticket Encours',
        width: 1700,
        height: 400,
        bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
        legend: 'none',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9  },
        curveType: 'function',
        pointSize: 10,

    };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home.aspx/GetLineChartData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, {
              calc: 'stringify',
              sourceColumn: 1,
              type: 'string',
              role: 'annotation'
            }]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart_Line")[0]);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}
```

**note:** you are using an old version of google charts,
which should no longer be used.

replace the script source, here...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

with `loader.js`...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

and the only other change is to the `load` statement, see above snippet...

---

**tooltips**

as for making the tooltips always showing,
we need to add the following chart option.
this will make the tooltip show when the point is hovered, *and* selected.

```
tooltip: {trigger: 'both'}
```

this options allows multiple selections...

```
selectionMode: 'multiple'
```

by default, when multiple selections are made,
the chart will show all the selections in one tooltip.
if you want a separate tooltip for all points, need to add this option.

```
aggregationTarget: 'none'
```

then on the chart's `'ready'` event,
we'll manually select all the points.
to select a row, we provide an array of objects with keys for the rows & columns to select

```
chart.setSelection([{row: 0, column: 1}, {row: 1, column: 1}]);
```

to select all, we'll use data table method `getSortedRows`
this will give us an array of all the row indexes

so, to select all rows for column 1...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  var rows = [];
  data.getSortedRows({column: 0}).forEach(function (row) {
    rows.push({row: row, column: 1});
  });
  chart.setSelection(rows);
});
```

here's the full snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        title: 'Ticket Encours',
        width: 1700,
        height: 400,
        bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
        legend: 'none',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9  },
        curveType: 'function',
        pointSize: 10,
        tooltip: {trigger: 'both'},
        selectionMode: 'multiple',
        aggregationTarget: 'none'
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home.aspx/GetLineChartData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, {
              calc: 'stringify',
              sourceColumn: 1,
              type: 'string',
              role: 'annotation'
            }]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart_Line")[0]);

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
              var rows = [];
              data.getSortedRows({column: 0}).forEach(function (row) {
                rows.push({row: row, column: 1});
              });
              chart.setSelection(rows);
            });

            chart.draw(view, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is a working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
      title: 'Ticket Encours',
      width: 1700,
      height: 400,
      bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
      legend: 'none',
      isStacked: true,
      hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 9  },
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 10,
      tooltip: {trigger: 'both'},
      selectionMode: 'multiple',
      aggregationTarget: 'none'
  };

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [1, 115],
    [2, 116],
    [3, 117],
    [4, 118],
    [5, 119],
    [6, 125],
    [7, 135],
    [8, 145],
    [9, 142],
    [10, 140],
    [11, 136],
    [12, 128],
    [13, 120],
    [14, 118],
    [15, 117],
    [16, 116],
    [17, 112],
    [18, 110],
    [19, 110],
    [20, 109],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart_Line").get(0));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rows = [];
    data.getSortedRows({column: 0}).forEach(function (row) {
      rows.push({row: row, column: 1});
    });
    chart.setSelection(rows);
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_Line"></div>
```

Comment: thank you soo much it's worked like the code snippet but it's not showing the numbers like you do

Comment: my eng is pretty bad .. run your code snippet you will see a blue number above the points .. in my code i can't seen them

Comment: yes, make sure you're drawing the chart with the data view and not the data table (have to leave, be back in an hour)

Comment: its not showing anything when im drawing the chart , the chart is desipir

Comment: sorry! there was a mistake in my code, need to use the `new` keyword when creating the data view, here --> `new google.visualization.DataView(data);`

Comment: hello WH i really need your help please if you can help me , i can't post any question here , my problem is in google chart , i hope youu see my message , thanks

Comment: what do you need help with?

Comment: please take a look here [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012334/stack-bar-google-visualisation ]